# Is the order of multiple INNER JOIN-s related with the tables relashionship?

Tags: sql-server, join

I want to join some tables using INNER JOIN statement.Some of them have the  many to many relashionship ,some one to many and some one to one. I want to know does the order of INNER JOIN-s statement matters and is it related with the type of relashionship(One to one,one to many etc.)? So does these three codes below output the same result?

```html
SELECT ....
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (table2 INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.col=table3.col)
ON table1.col=table2.col


SELECT ....
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (table2 INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.col=table3.col)
ON table1.col=table3.col

SELECT ....
FROM table2
INNER JOIN (table1 INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.col=table3.col)
ON table3.col=table2.col
```

And can I replace the INNER JOIN of two tables with this code below?So does this code below represents the inner join of table 1 and table2?

```html
SELECT ...
FROM table1,table2
WHERE (table1.col=table2.col)
```

Comment: I don't think it does. But for each SQL snippet view the execution plan to see if you can spot any differences there

Comment: "does these three codes below output the same result?" Do you mean query plan? Because for actual _result_, you can just test this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly order of joins is not matter.

Better to use

```
select ...
from table1
inner join table2 on table2.col=table1.col
inner join table3 on table3.col=table1.col
```

Yes, INNER JOIN's could be replaced with

```
WHERE t1.col=t2.col
```

And SQL plan will be the same.
But if there are other filters in where condition - will mix.

Also, if there is additional join conditions - better to filter out all not required records first.

Comment: "INNER JOIN's could be replaced with `WHERE`" But, like you said, people shouldn't do this if they can avoid it! `JOIN`s were made to avoid this and come with lots of other benefits. _Although_, to be fair, I do sometimes feel I have to use `where`s to avoid the terrible `join` syntax of Microsoft Access... ugh.

Comment: @underscore_d never replace inner joins with `where` or `left join` and condition. Inner joins are always faster and better way, also easier to read. In some conditions, when you check your execution plan, you can compare inner join vs where query. Sometimes it's the same and both fast, but mostly inner join will be faster with better execution plan

Comment: Doesn't the order of JOINS matters even if the primary key of one of these tables is composed of 2 or more foreign keys?

Comment: @user5827762 don't worry, if you are using joins, you are doing your best with SQL. Server will handle it for you, it does not matter

Comment: @krtek Sure, "never", except when the crappy Access syntax means you don't have time to sit there nesting `inner join (a inner join (b inner join (noooooo` and getting that mess exactly right. Look, my post was in agreement with you, but I mentioned one example where I admit to going against my own advice due to the limitations of the platform. Apparently that wasn't nuanced enough.

Comment: @krtek Is it possible to use TRANSFORM()without PIVOT() in the end?

Comment: @underscore_d yes, nesting joins like this is a pretty bad idea, I don't even know why should anyone do that :S

Comment: @krtek I couldn't believe Access didn't have proper `join` syntax supporting multiple tables, and yet here we are. I've not used the 2016 version but might pessimistically assume it hasn't changed this.

Comment: @underscore_d yes it does not. You can't use TRANSFORM() on sql-server

Comment: Transform on access?

Answer (score 0):

It makes absolutely no difference to the results. Because you are using only inner joins, only the matches in all three tables will show.

If you were to use a LEFT OUTER join and an INNER join in one query, you could vary the resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

For INNER JOIN it will give same result but with other type of join it will give different result.
for example:

```
SELECT ....
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (table2 INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.col=table3.col)
ON table1.col=table2.col
```

above is equivalent to

```
SELECT ....
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (
    Select table2.col 
    From table2 INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.col=table3.col
    ) tbl
ON table1.col=tbl.col
```

First it will do INNER JOIN of table2 & table3 then the table1 will left joined with the result